# Prove $n - 2 < \frac{n^2 - n}{12}$ by Mathematical Induction

Tags: induction

I am trying to prove the following $n - 2 < (n^2 - n)/12$ when $n > 10$ by Mathematical Induction. The following is what I've come up so far (please bare with me):

Property to be proven $P(n)$:

$$
n - 2 < (n^2 - n)/12 \hspace{.5cm}\leftarrow P(n)
$$

*[For now I am assuming to solve for integer values, thus for the basis step I've used]* Show that $P(11)$ is true:

$$
11 - 2 < (11^2 - 11)/12 \hspace{.5cm} \leftarrow \text{basis } P(11)\\
9 < 110/12 \\
108/12 < 110/12
$$

Hence $P(11)$ is true.

Show that for every integer $k \geq 11$, if $P(k)$ is true then $P(k + 1)$ is also true:

Suppose that $k$ is any integer with $k \geq 11$ such that

$$
k - 2 < (k^2 - k)/12. \hspace{.5cm} \leftarrow P(k) \text{ inductive hypothesis}
$$

*[We must show that $P(k + 1)$ is true. That is:]* We must show that

$$
(k + 1) - 2 < ((k + 1)^2 - (k + 1))/12. \hspace{.5cm} \leftarrow P(k + 1)
$$

or, equivalently,

$$
k - 1 < (k^2 + k)/12.
$$

or, also,

$$
12k - 12 < k^2 + k
$$

Now, from the inductive hypothesis:

$$
k - 2 < (k^2 - k)/12 \\
12(k - 2) < k^2 - k \hspace{.5cm} \text{multiply the inequality by 12} \\
12k - 24 < k^2 - k \\
(12k - 24) + 2k < (k^2 - k) + 2k \hspace{.5cm} \text{add } 2k \text{ on both sides}\\
(12k - 12) + (2k - 12) < k^2 + k \hspace{.5cm} \text{reordering and grouping}
$$

Because $2k - 12 > 0$ since $k \geq 11$.

$$
k^2 + k > 12k -12
$$

*[as was to be shown.]*

At this time, I am unsure whether the statement "Because $2k - 12 > 0$ since $k \geq 11$." allows me to complete the proof. Also, I'm unsure how to proceed otherwise.

I hope to obtain feedbacks from everyone in regards of this proofing.

Thank you in advance, and have a nice day.

Comment: That's ok as $2k-12>0$ when $k>6$, which is a easy observation

Comment: $k >10$ because .... it is....  If your hypothesis is that $k > 10$ then ... you are allowed to use it.

Comment: Alternative proof: $n^2-13n+24>n^2-13n+22=(n-2)(n-11)$ and the latter is $\ge0$ for $n\ge11$.

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio, Does this imply that if $n > 10$, $k > 6$ is allowed? I mean algebraically, $2k > 12$, $k > 6$, but I am still new to mathematical induction to relate between how these statements constitute a valid proof.

Comment: @AdiDaman You are totally right that you can simply use this fact and also induction is just a lazy way to prove things actually

Comment: Okay great, this helps a lot!

Also quick note; thank you fleablood for the affirmation, as well as to Jean-Claude Arbaut for the alternative proof.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

For $n=11$, it is correct

If for a given $n$ the inequality is correct, we are going to prove that the inequality is correct for $n+1$

$\frac{(n+1)^{2}-(n+1)}{12}=\frac{n^{2}-n}{12}+\frac{2n}{12}$

For $n>10$, $\frac{2n}{12}>1$

Therefore,

$\frac{(n+1)^{2}-(n+1)}{12}>\frac{n^{2}-n}{12}+1$

$\frac{(n+1)^{2}-(n+1)}{12}>n-2+1$

$\frac{(n+1)^{2}-(n+1)}{12}>(n+1)-2$

Thus proving the inequality is correct for all integers $n>10$ by induction

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and time; I am sorry, I am having trouble understanding of how you convert $\frac{(n + 1)^2 - (n +1)}{12} > \frac{n^2 - n}{12} + 1$ to $\frac{(n + 1)^2 - (n +1)}{12} > n - 2 + 1$.

Comment: I do that because i assume $\frac{n^{2}-n}{12}>n-2$ i.e. i tried to prove that if the inequality is true for a given $n$, then it is also true for $n+1$.

Comment: Duly noted, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove
an inequality of the form
$f(n) < g(n)$
for $n \ge n_0$
is to

(1) show that $f(n_0) < g(n_0)$

and

(2) if $n \ge n_0$ then
$f(n+1)-f(n) \le g(n+1)-g(n)
$.

This says that $g(n)$ increases
at least as fast as $f(n)$
so $f(n)$ can never catch up.

In this case
$f(n+1)-f(n) = 1$,
so we need to show that
$g(n+1)-g(n) \ge 1$.

Here,
$g(n+1)-g(n)
=\dfrac{(n+1)^2-(n+1)}{12}-\dfrac{n^2-n}{12}
=\dfrac{(n+1)^2-n^2-((n+1)-n)}{12}
=\dfrac{2n}{12}
=\dfrac{n}{6}
$
so
$f(n+1)-f(n)
\le g(n+1)-g(n)
$
for $n \ge 6$.

Since
$f(11) < g(11)$,
$f(n) < g(n)$
for $n \ge 11$.

The advantage of this method
is that we do not need to consider
$g(n)-f(n)$,
so the calculations are often simpler.

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for the response! However, $f(n)$ and $f(n_0)$ would be the same function as $g(n)$? (Sorry, just being explicit).